# Bytes common factor

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, operators

If I have bytes `A`, `B`, `C`, `E` and `F`, and I do an operation (like XORing) `A^B = E`, `A^C = F`, how can I do an operation on `F` and `E` to get back char `A`? It is a common factor between the two operations.

Comment: You've got 3 unknowns (A, B, C) and 2 knowns (E, F). If you can work out A from E, F then you can also trivially work out B and C (B = E^A, etc). This means you've invented the perfect compression algorithm (compress any 3 bytes into 2!) with which you can massively profit from. Alternatively its not possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible.

A simple counter example is the case where A = B = C. Then E and F are both 0, so do not contain any information to recover A.

Comment: so there is no way to do it !?

Comment: E and F both being 0 does _not_ imply they don't have information. The byte value 0 has just as much information as any other byte value. Its still not possible, I agree, but your explanation is wrong.

Comment: Indeed they contain information; but nothing of any use to recover A. Perhaps I'm not being clear enough; it is Friday after all.

Comment: This is completely fine to me. Perhaps a more concrete example with explicit values could convince more people. E.g. showing that both cases `A=B=C=0` and `A=B=C=1` lead to the same `E=F=0`, so knowing the values of `E,F` is not enough to discriminate between the two cases.